# Стоит ли использовать .editorconfig?

Tags: python, flake8

Пишу проект на django. Собираюсь использовать flake8 с дополнительными плагинами в качестве линтера и black в качестве форматировщика. Вопрос, стоит ли связываться с .editorconfig или можно обойтись без него. В чем его принципиальные отличия от flake8 и не будет ли он конфликтовать с ним?